# Get a value from a closed file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I was looking a post at this link: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/

The function is

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

and to get a value,

```
Sub TestGetValue()
    p = "c:\XLFiles\Budget"
    f = "Budget.xls"
    s = "Sheet1"
    a = "A1"
    MsgBox GetValue(p, f, s, a)
End Sub
```

and to loop

```
Sub TestGetValue2()
    p = "c:\XLFiles\Budget"
    f = "Budget.xls"
    s = "Sheet1"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To 100
        For c = 1 To 12
            a = Cells(r, c).Address
            Cells(r, c) = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
        Next c
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I think it's very well written. However, I met two problems with it:

1. If the source cell in closed file is blank ("" in VBA), I would got 0 in getvalue.

I wonder how I can pass 0 to 0 and pass "" to ""?
Is there a bug for `ExecuteExcel4Macro`?

2. Suppose the source file has different extensions: xls, xlsx, xlsm, or xlsb,...
   How can I get a dynamic path?

I tried to eliminate file extension in the path and use

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & ".xl?]" & sheet & "'!" & _
          Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

However, it didn't work in `ExecuteExcel4Macro`.

Comment: `f = "Budget.xls"` You're setting and passing the file with the extension so not sure why that's a problem. Edit: I guess you could modify the function to take on a fifth argument for extension.

Comment: `ExecuteExcel4Macro` is loooooooooooong deprecated. Is there any reason you can't just `Application.Run` it?

Comment: Sorry, I actually mean  f = "Budget"

Answer (score 1):

This is normal Excel behaviour. If you put a formula in a cell A1

`=B1`

then A1 will also show a 0

You can get a value with this code:

```
Public Function GetValue(sFileName As String, sSheetName As String, sAddress As String) As Variant

    Dim oSheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Workbooks.Add(sFileName)
        GetValue = .Sheets(sSheetName).Range(sAddress).Value
        .Close
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: I agree with you. it seems that open another workbook then do the manipulation is better than get value directly from a closed workbook

Comment: btw, why is normal excel behaviour shows A1=0? I know it does show 0, but I'm just curious about it, as there is nothing in B1

Comment: Just guessing, but Excel probably prefers the use of *Type Long* if no other type is specified. So excel dims the value as *Type Long* if the cell it points to is empty. Therefore empty translates as 0.